# MVC Project will not load in my VS 2017 environment because of MSBuild issue

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

My team has an MVC Web Application that was built in .NET 4.5.2, but been upgraded to 4.6.1. For everyone on my team, they can load it fine into their instances of VS 2017, but the project will not load in mine. I get a popup error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I can get the project to load into VS if I comment out this line in the .csproj file

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

But obviously this is needed because leaving it out causes all kinds of odd MSBuild compilation errors.

Reiterating, this problem has not occurred for my coworkers!

I have even run the Repair option in Visual Studio Installer and it didn't remedy the situation.

Since I cannot run the build on this project, I checked the value of the MSBuildBinPath variable from a different project (by inserting a message statement into the project file) and have verified that the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file is present in that location.

Comment: Does it help to change the bin path reference to `$(MSBuildToolsPath)`? the tool path may be different for 2017

Comment: @MartinUllrich I did not try this specifically. In searching for an answer to the problem, I came across similar issues where switching from $(MSBuildToolsPath) to $(MSBuildBinPath) solved their problem, but I never tried the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this resolved by removing the project from the solution and then re-adding it.

Simply unloading and reloading DID NOT solve the issue, it needed to be removed and re-added.

I am not sure what this accomplished behind the scenes, but it is working now.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues

Answer (score 0):

Try clear the Visual Studio cache and re-setting your Visual Studio settings.

Detail steps:

**Clear the Visual Studio cache**: Delete the contents from the following folders:

1. `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`
2. `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon`

**Re-setting your Visual Studio settings**: Go to Start > Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 and run the command:

```
devenv /ResetSettings
```

Comment: This might work, but by the time I saw this response, I had already come to the resolution I posted below.